# Building a "hollow world" error using cmake and opencv: undefined reference to viz's moduls

Tags: opencv, cmake

My c++ source code:

```cpp
int main(){
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image = imread(argv[1]);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.
}
```

This is just easy code to test opencv.

The CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION  3.8)
set(PROJECT_NAME testCVCL)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED) 
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                test.cc)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Compilation is fine, but linking has error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_viz.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `typeinfo for vtkWriter'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_viz.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `vtkPolyData::SetStrips(vtkCellArray*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libopencv_hdf.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `H5P_CLS_DATASET_CREATE_ID_g'
....
....
and so on
```

Above error almost generated by **libopencv_viz** and **libopencv_hdf**.

I am sure those library exist in "/usr/lib".

So I feel confused.

Comment: I have solved it. "hd5" "vtk" "glew" are needed by opencv with cmake-find_package

Comment: put your solution into an answer. Preferably, with correct code to call `find_package`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I installed these packages:

```
vtk
hdf5
glew
```

in my computer, now I can build the project fine.

I have not modify above code.